# Is there a Java classpath-like feature for server-side Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing

When using JUnit and Maven in Java, one can have separate property files for `src/main` and `src/test`. This allows different configuration for code and tests, having Maven to manage the resources by using Java classpath.

Is there a similar way in Javascript code run by Node.js? I use Mocha for unit-testing and Grunt for task management.

Code example for `script.js`:

```
var config = require('./config/dev/app.js');

exports.getFileName = function() {
    return config.fileName; // returns 'code.txt'
}
```

What I need is to make the `script.js` use different config file when being required in a `test.js` unit test like this:

```
var assert = require('assert');
var s = require('./script.js');

describe('Test', function () {
    it('should use different config file', function() {
        assert.equal('test.txt', s.getFileName());
    });
});
```

Is there a way to use different configuration `./config/test/app.js` in the `script.js` without having to alter the code of `script.js`? What I really try to avoid is to adjust the code to support unit tests. Instead, I want to achieve similar functionality such as mentioned Java classpath.

Comment: I don't think so, but you could emulate it reading an environment variable (via process.env.ENV_VARIABLE) to decide what path to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not found any elegant solution out there on the web so I have implemented and published my own.
Check it out here: https://npmjs.org/package/app-config

Using the `app-config` plugin, only the `script.js` needs to get changed this way:

```
var config = require('app-config').app;

exports.getFileName = function() {
    return config.fileName; // returns 'code.txt'
}
```

The app needs to be run this way for example

1. `NODE_ENV=dev node script.js`
2. `NODE_ENV=unitTest mocha test.js`

Depending on the `NODE_ENV` environmental variable, the right set of configuration files will be loaded by the `app-config` plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code.

Script.js

```
var config;
if(process.env.dev===true){
   config = require('./config/dev/config.js');
}

if(process.env.prod===true){
   config = require('./config/prod/config.js');
}


exports.getFileName = function() {
    return config.fileName; // returns 'code.txt'
}
```

test.js

```
//set the environment here
process.env.dev = true;
var assert = require('assert');
var s = require('./script.js');

describe('Test', function () {
    it('should use different config file', function() {
        assert.equal('test.txt', s.getFileName());
    });
});
```

Comment: I was thinking of something you suggest but I do not really like this way for two reasons:

1. I have to have put the IF fork of require function into every module and keep in mind not forgetting it.

2. There must be some single-point-of-entry module which either sets the dev or test variable to true in `process.env` depending on the mode the app is running in.

I.e. having to not forget to use all this stuff while coding will sooner or later lead to forgetting it and causing unpredictable results of the app. I hope there is some better way to achieve the goal.